# Wildcards (.*) with two optional (?) regex parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have two optional parts in my regex - either of them can be found in matching string, and also both of them can at the same time.

Both of those optional parts consist of a wildcard (I wrote `.*` here but it can be say `[a-zA-Z]+`; anyway the point is that second part of the regex (`Bar`) matches the wildcard if greedy matching is applied).

It's best illustrated by this Firebug output:

```javascript
>>> /(Foo.*)?(Bar.*)?/.exec("FooAA")
["FooAA", "FooAA", undefined] // OK

>>> /(Foo.*)?(Bar.*)?/.exec("BarAA")
["BarAA", undefined, "BarAA"] // OK

>>> /(Foo.*)?(Bar.*)?/.exec("FooAABarAA")
["FooAABarAA", "FooAABarAA", undefined] // I'd like to have ["FooAABarAA", "FooAA", "BarAA"]
```

Is there a way to construct a regex matching my three test cases above?

I can use sth like

```
/((Foo.*)(Bar.*))|(Foo.*)?(Bar.*)?/.exec("FooAABarAA")
```

but I want to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need non-greedy wildcards. This works for me:

```
/^(Foo.*?)?(Bar.*?)?$/
```

Comment: Hmm I tried that but without leading `^` and trailing `$` and it didn't work (returned `["Foo", "Foo", undefined]`). Works fine with it. Thanks!

Comment: You actually gave to keep trailing `$`(But can get rid of `^`). But since you are catching all the characters in the end it makes sense anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply be able to make the first wildcard non-greedy like this:

```
/(Foo.*?)?(Bar.*)?/
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work: `/(Foo.*?)?(Bar.*)?/.exec("FooAABarAA")` -> `["Foo", "Foo", undefined]`. See Agares's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 /((?:Foo|Bar)[\s\S]*?)(?=Foo|Bar|$)/
```

(to be sure to have the largest possible substring before the next occurence)

example:

```
console.log('FoodAABarAABarBBFoo'.match(/((?:Foo|Bar)[\s\S]*?)(?=Foo|Bar|$)/g));
```

Comment: `/((?:Foo|Bar)[/s/S]*?)(?=Foo|Bar|$)/.exec("FooAABarAA");` -> `null`,